# How to implement Iterator for boxed values?

Tags: rust

I have a struct that gives numbers by method `next` from trait `Iterator`:

```
struct Numbers{
    number: usize,
    count: usize
}

impl Iterator for Numbers {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.count > 0 {
            self.count -= 1;
            return Some(self.number);
        }

        return None;
    }
}

fn main(){
    let numbers = Numbers{
        number: 777,
        count: 10
    };

    for n in numbers {
        println!{"{:?}", n};
    }
}
```

It's work properly with `usize` type.
But same code with Box type gives a compilation error:

```
struct Numbers{
    number: Box<usize>,
    count: usize
}

impl Iterator for Numbers {
    type Item = Box<usize>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.count > 0 {
            self.count -= 1;
            return Some(self.number);
        }

        return None;
    }
}

fn main(){
    let numbers = Numbers{
        number: Box::new(777),
        count: 10
    };

    for n in numbers {
        println!{"{:?}", n};
    }
}
```

> ./numbers.rs:12:25: 12:29 error: cannot move out of borrowed content
>
> ./numbers.rs:12             return Some(self.number);

How to implement Iterator for boxed values properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This comes down to Rust’s ownership model and the distinction between copy and move semantics; `Box<T>` has move semantics, not implementing `Copy`, and so `return Some(self.number);` would move `self.number`, taking ownership of it; but this is not permitted because it would require consuming `self`, which is only taken by mutable reference.

You have a few choices (where I write “the object with move semantics,” I mean in this specific case `self.number`):

1. Don’t return the object with move semantics, return something else with copy semantics reference, such as a reference instead of the boxed value (returning a reference will require the iterator object to be different from the object being iterated over so that you can write the lifetime in `Item`; thus it doesn’t apply to your specific use case) or the unboxed number.
2. Construct a new value to return based on the object with move semantics:

   ```rust
   impl Iterator for Numbers {
       type Item = Box<usize>;

       fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
           if self.count > 0 {
               self.count -= 1;
               Some(Box::new(self.number))
           } else {
               None
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Clone the object with move semantics (this is a simplified form of the second option, really):

   ```rust
   impl Iterator for Numbers {
       type Item = Box<usize>;

       fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
           if self.count > 0 {
               self.count -= 1;
               Some(self.number.clone())
           } else {
               None
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Construct a new value to substitute in place of the object with move semantics:

   ```rust
   use std::mem;

   impl Iterator for Numbers {
       type Item = Box<usize>;

       fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
           if self.count > 0 {
               self.count -= 1;
               let number = mem::replace(&mut self.number, Box::new(0));
               // self.number now contains 0
               Some(number)
           } else {
               None
           }
       }
   }
   ```